# How to round float numbers in Python?

Tags: python, rounding, rounding-error

I know there are different questions like this; and I searched my question on stackoverflow and many other webs, and basically the easiest way to do this is using the round/2 function, but the round function didn't work properly...
Here's part of my code using the round function:

```
ad=150
ad_percent = 75
ap=150
ap_percent=55
armor_pen=35
enemy_armor=125
enemy_max_hp=1000

ap = ap_percent * ap / 100
ad = ad_percent * ad / 100

armor_less = armor_pen * enemy_armor / 100
enemy_armor = enemy_armor - armor_less
# Till now, all is good.

round(ad)
print(ad)
```

**Output**

> 112.5

So... It's not working. How can I make that variable round to 113?

Thanks for helping.

Comment: You need to store the result, or print it : `print(round(ad))`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`round()` returns the rounded value](https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/functions.html#round); it doesn't modify its argument (indeed, it couldn't, in Python's data model (unless `__round__` on a custom object had been modified to mutate the object itself, but that would be very, very icky, and I digress)).

You'll need to assign the return value of `round()`, in other words e.g.

```
ad = round(ad)
```

instead.

Answer (score 0):

You are properly rounding but you are not storming it in a variable to print afterwards.

You can try:

```
print(round(ad))
```

Or:

```
ad_rounded = round(ad)
print(ad_rounded)
```

Hope it helps! Let me know if it did.